# Symfony Capifony Setting stage during deployment

Tags: php, symfony, capifony

While deploying a Symfony application using Capifony I am having issues changing the stage while issuing commands. I would like to push my database from production to beta when deploying.

This is my attempt at doing this. Here is the `beta.rb` file:

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{domain}/deploy/beta"

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

# Move database from production to beta and dev
# Set stage to production, move database to local
set :stage, "prod"
after "deploy", "database:move:to_local"

# Set stage back to beta, move database to remote beta
set :stage, "beta"
after "deploy", "database:move:to_remote"
```

In the past I have stored the cap files outside of the project using capistrano and symfony < 2 and used scripts to deal with stuff like this. With it now in the project it doesn't make sense to have scripts in the project.

Am I able to change the stage on the fly when executing commands like this?  Or should I create a task to call an external script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DoctrineMigrationsBundle` for such purposes. This bundle is very versatile and has neat console command line interface, which you can simply build into your `capifony` script. Read about it in the symfony and its own reference docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst

Comment: Thanks for this info. This bundle does look useful, but I am primarily interested in moving data.